# Convert values from dalton to kilodalton (Divide values by 1000)

Tags: command-line, text-processing

How can we convert dalton values into kilodalton by using shell commands? I have a list of values in [daltons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_atomic_mass_unit). There are 1000 daltons in a kilodalton, so it is necessary to divide each value by a thousand.

Sample data:

```
12345.09
236575.665
18865.41
45678.87
```

Desired output:

```
12.34509
236.575665
18.86541
45.67887
```

Comment: Divide by 1000. Read in value, remove units, add /1000 to end, and feed into bc. Add units back on. Sed, awk and bc is tools needed.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I have edited the post kindly consider it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### With [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)

The task here is simply to divide each value by a thousand. There are several good ways to do this--on *all* the values in your file--with just a single command. Suppose your numbers are in a file called `dalton.txt` and, as in the example you showed, are one value per line. Here's one way, using AWK:

```
awk '{ print $0 / 1000.0 }' dalton.txt
```

That operates on each line. `$0` in AWK indicates the whole line. As written that outputs to your terminal but you can [redirect the output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) to a file. This sends the output to `kilodalton.txt` (overwriting it if it already exists):

```
awk '{ print $0 / 1000.0 }' dalton.txt > kilodalton.txt
```

**However, you may want to customize the precision.** Given the example input you showed us, the output to your terminal or the file from using those commands is:

```
12.3451
236.576
18.8654
45.6789
```

The your output example, each output value retains the same precision (in terms of number of digits of information shown) as the corresponding input value. If you want that:

```
awk '{ printf "%.*g\n", length($0), $0 / 1000.0 }' dalton.txt
```

This still truncates trailing zeros after the decimal point, since that's how the `printf` function's `g` [format specifier](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Control-Letters) behaves. (Your examples don't make clear if you want that.) The way it works is simply to specify a precision that is always at least as high as the number of digits in the input, but making it the total length of the input line, `length($0)`.

That command may of course also be redirected to a file, and its output is exactly the output shown in your question:

```
12.34509
236.575665
18.86541
45.67887
```

Often you may want to specify the same precision for each entry, either as the total number of figures shown or as the number of figures show after the decimal point. For example, to show a total of 6 figures for each value (the first line will be `12.3451`), use:

```
awk '{ printf "%.6g\n", $0 / 1000.0 }' dalton.txt
```

Or to show 3 figures *after* the decimal place for each value (the first line will be `12.345`) use:

```
awk '{ printf "%.3f\n", $0 / 1000.0 }' dalton.txt
```

Although it is possible to write a loop in a shell script that reads the data, that's more complicated and [it is rarely the best approach when a simple command will do it for you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Even if this is part of a larger shell script already, shells are [glue languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language#Glue_languages) that are meant to be used to call whatever tools are best suited to a task. So I suggest using this `awk` method, [**terdon's excellent `perl` method**](https://askubuntu.com/a/959182/22949), or the like.

Answer (score 12):

I would just use `perl`:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $_/1000' file
12.34509
236.575665
18.86541
45.67887
```

Or `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%.6f\n", $1/1000}' file
12.345090
236.575665
18.865410
45.678870
```

Comment: The `perl` way is particularly good because it doesn't require anything special to keep all the figures the OP showed in their example output.

Answer (score 6):

### General description

Assume the numeric value is stored in the variable `dalton`. Then it works with values that are big enough to create non-zero values with the simple construct `$(())`.

Example:

```
$ dalton=3800
$ echo $(($dalton/1000))
3
```

To get correct rounding to the nearest integer

```
$ echo $(( ($dalton+500)/1000 ))
4
```

You have more features if you install `bc`.

```
sudo apt-get install bc

$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale=3                        # set the number of decimals
dalton=3800
dalton/1000
3.800
(dalton+0,5)/1000
(standard_in) 4: syntax error  # use decimal point (not comma)
(dalton+0.5)/1000              # add 0.5 to get correct rounding
3.800
dalton=3800.8
(dalton+0.5)/1000
3.801
dalton=3800.2
(dalton+0.5)/1000
3.800
quit
$
```

In a shellscript you can pipe the input into bc like so,

```
echo "scale=3
($dalton+0.5)/1000" | bc
```

Which can be tested interactively too,

```
$ dalton=3800.8
$ echo "scale=3
($dalton+0.5)/1000" | bc
3.801
$
```

### Shellscript

Create a shellscript with the name `converter`

```
#!/bin/bash

dalton=

function convert2kilo {

 echo "scale=6
 ($dalton+0.0005)/1000" | bc 
}
########################################################################

# main

########################################################################

while read dalton
do
 convert2kilo
done
```

and an input file with the name `input.data`

```
12345.09
236575.665
18865.41
45678.87
1.0008
1.0002
```

Make the shellscript executable

```
chmod ugo+x converter
```

Run the shellscript

```
$ < input.data ./converter 
12.345090
236.575665
18.865410
45.678870
.001001
.001000
$
```

Answer (score 3):

This little script would be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash    

values="$1"

echo "Source of values: $values"

while read -e name; do            

        results=$(bc <<< "scale=4; ($name/1000)")
        echo "$results"

done < "$values"
```

Usage:

1. Make file executable with:

   ```
   chmod u+x dalton.sh
   ```
2. Run and pass in the path to the data file or file name:

   ```
   ./dalton.sh data.txt
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a text file called `daltons`, for instance, with all of the numeric values you want to convert, in a single column.

```
awk '{kDa=$1/1000; print kDa}' daltons >> result
```

Where `kDa` is a variable to store the operation, and `$1` will take each of the row values. Finally, the results are stored in the file `result`.

Comment: Although this doesn't have the output precision the original poster showed in their example output (for example, it gives `12.3451` instead of `12.34509`), this is a generally good approach. Assigning to a variable (`kDa`) before printing arguably makes the command more-self documenting but isn't needed, since `print`'s argument can be an arithmetic expression. That is, `awk '{print $1/1000}' daltons >> result` has the same effect.